# Screenshot language for AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store

When submitting screenshots of multilanguage application to AppStore, which language my screenshots have to be? Do they have to be in default language or any language?

Comment: I believe screenshots are on a per-language basis. Ergo separate screenshots for each language.

Comment: You can't change the screenshots once the app's been approved, so localize them while you can. You get another chance with each binary update (approval process).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will submit a different set of screenshots for every localization of your app.

Comment: What if I upload screenshots with English translation for every language? Will not my app be rejected in this case?

Comment: No, you should be able to do that.

Comment: It's is acceptable to submit the same set of screenshots to different locales.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload different screenshots for different app stores, and if at all possible, you should localize the screenshots for each language you support. You can upload new screenshots in the metadata, in the same place you'll edit the descriptions and keywords for different app stores.